# Undefined behavior of default constructor and destructor of anonymous union?

Tags: c++, unions

The following code gives different compilation result with g++ 7.3 and clang++ 7.0, but to my knowledge all of copy constructor of S1, S2, S3 is deleted and none of the instantiation should success.

Question:

1. Is such case (S1, S2) undefined in C++ standard?
2. What is the difference between anonymous union without constructor/destructor implementation and named union with default constructor/destructor?

```
template <typename T>
struct S1
{
    union
    {
        T payload;
    };

    S1() {}
    ~S1() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct S2
{
    union
    {
        T payload;
    };

    S2() {}
    virtual ~S2() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct S3
{
    union U
    {
        T payload;

        U()  = default;
        ~U() = default;
    } storage;

    S3() {}
    ~S3() {}
};

#include <iostream>

struct A // overloaded A() & ~A()
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        S1<A> a;
        auto  b = a; // g++ OK, clang++ OK
    }
    {
        S2<A> a;
        auto  b = a; // g++ fail, clang++ OK
    }
    {
        S3<A> a;
        auto  b = a; // g++ fail, clang++ fail
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With both GCC and Clang, type traits show that `S1<A>` and `S2<A>` are both _copy/move-constructible_, while `S3<A>` is not. Weird.

Comment: Why would the copy constructors be deleted?  `A` is trivially copyable/movable, so all the unions get a copy and a move constructor that are themselves trivial.  (Also, what is the error?  This isn’t about undefined behavior at runtime!)

Comment: @DavisHerring A is not trivially copyable/movable for the non-default ~A() implementation, but A is trivially copy/move assignable

Comment: @MidoriYakumo: Sorry, I was sloppy: `A` (and thence each union containing it) gets a trivial copy constructor (deprecatedly, despite the user-provided destructor) but is not trivially copyable.  It gets no move constructor at all, but is still “movable” in that `A(xvalue_A)` works, so the union *does* get a defaulted, trivial move constructor.